# What color scheme does the Spongebob character use?

Tags: color-theory

We have a homework regarding color schemes and I chose Spongebob as my subject. At first I was thinking that it uses a triadic scheme since it uses blue, red, and yellow, and brown is just a combination of the three. However, I'm not sure if that is how the color scheme works, as brown is not a part of a the basic color wheel. I'm really confused. I even thought brown is just a darker shade of orange.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Photoshop trick to find an average color scheme.

- Starting with an image, I chose one with the main BobSponge's characters.

[image: bobsponge]

- From Photoshop apply a Pixelate filter, or choose an **Online Pixelate Filter Maker** like [pinetools.com/pixelate-effect-image](http://pinetools.com/pixelate-effect-image). With this you get a small color map from which to extract the most important or essential colors of an image.

[image: color map]